# Array of all NSDate for a week

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nsdate

I would like to have a function that takes a week number as input and returns an array of all the NSDates that this specific week is made by.

Something like this:

```
-(NSArray*)allDatesInWeek:(int)weekNumber {
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [calendar setFirstWeekday:2];
    NSDateComponents *todayComp = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
    int currentyear = todayComp.year;
    /* Calculate and return the date of weekNumber for current year */
```

}

How can this be done in a simple way?

Comment: What would the week number represent? The week in a given year?

Comment: No, it's not. I'm creating a schedule and want to display each page as weeks. I know some of the basic of NSDate and NSDateComponents and that i can get week from NSDateComponents, but now i'm doing reverse. Fetching all days in a week from either a NSDate or a week number.

Comment: There is 52 weeks a year, so between 1-52 :)

Comment: So...what year are you getting these dates for? What day of the week do you consider the first day of the week?

Comment: Current year (Can easy be done with `[NSDate date]` and convert it to NSComponents), Monday is first week but you will set this in NSCalendar `setFirstWeekday:` and not relevant to question.

Comment: @David - It is relevant to the question because it makes a difference in the result. You had already thought of this, which is good, but many people don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested.

```
-(NSArray*)allDatesInWeek:(int)weekNumber {
   // determine weekday of first day of year: 
   NSCalendar *greg = [[NSCalendar alloc] 
      initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
   NSDateComponents *coms = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
   comps.day = 1;
   NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
   NSDate *tomorrow = [greg dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:today];
   const NSTimeInterval kDay = [tomorrow timeIntervalSinceDate:today];
   comps = [greg components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
   comps.day = 1;
   comps.month = 1; 
   comps.hour = 12;
   NSDate *start = [greg dateFromComponents:comps];
   comps = [greg components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:start]; 
   if (weekNumber==1) {
       start = [start dateByAddingTimeInterval:-kDay*(comps.weekday-1)];
   } else {
       start = [start dateByAddingTimeInterval:
          kDay*(8-comps.weekday+7*(weekNumber-2))];
   }
   NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
   for (int i = 0; i<7; i++) {
       [result addObject:[start dateByAddingTimeInterval:kDay*i]];
   }
   return [NSArray arrayWithArray:result];
}
```

This assumes the first day of the week is Sunday, as stated in the NSDate API. Tweak if desired.

Comment: Doing your own arithmetic with dates is a very very bad idea. You should use NSDateComponents and NSCalendar methods. One day is not necessarily 24 hours, for example.

Comment: I **am** using NSDateComponents and NSCalendar. And the question wanted it to be solved in a **simple** way. Besides, this is a detail that can easily be fixed by whoever wants to use the algorithm.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for, tweaked it so it works correctly for my week settings. Thanks a lot for the answer Mundi. But Julien post made me a bit worried, is there a safer way to do it without using a homebrew algorithm?

Comment: He is just referring to 60*60*24. If you are not going to use the Aztec calendar that has a different number of seconds per day, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: 60*60*24 might also fail on days when clocks are switched to daylight saving time.

Comment: Edited the answer to address this issue.

Comment: I insist, don't imagine it's just for Aztec. Daylight saving is one of them but it's even more complex than that. The only good way to do proper calendar arithmetic is to use NSCalendar Calendrical Calculations. Seems tedious sometimes for adding one day is different than adding 24h, adding one week is different than adding 7 days.

Comment: I disagree. Your view is way too dogmatic. **Programming languages are there to help solve problems, not for catechism.** The problem is confined to the present-day Gregorian calendar, the solution is robust and efficient.

Comment: @Julien isn't being overly dogmatic, but is talking about preventing unforeseen issues from cropping up in your code. The present day Gregorian calendar has many examples of days that are not exactly 24 hours. The solution as presented above could fail for date ranges that include such days. Besides which, using NSCalendar the results are simpler and more readable (see my solution below).

Comment: @evanflash is right. Where do you think all these "alarm did not trigger on DST change/New year change" bugs can come from…

Comment: Alright, alright. I think we are beating a dead horse here. I have moved on in the last 1.5 years and probably would not write the exact same code myself.

Answer (score 5):

This solution relies entirely on NSCalendar without making any assumptions about the user's calendar.

```
-(NSArray*)allDatesInWeekContainingDate:(NSDate*)referenceDate {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSInteger ordinalityOfInput = [calendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
                                                      inUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit
                                                     forDate:referenceDate];
    NSDateComponents *componentsToAdd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    componentsToAdd.day = -1 * (ordinalityOfInput - 1);
    NSDate *startDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:componentsToAdd toDate:referenceDate options:0];
    NSInteger numDaysInWeek = [calendar maximumRangeOfUnit:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit].length;
    NSMutableArray *allDays = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numDaysInWeek];
    NSDateComponents *curDayOffset = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    for (int curDay=0; curDay < numDaysInWeek; curDay++) {
        curDayOffset.day = curDay;
        [allDays addObject:[calendar dateByAddingComponents:curDayOffset toDate:startDate options:0]];
    }
    return allDays;
}
```