# Days of the week in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, days

How do I do this?  This is what I've tried so far and it keeps erroring saying  naughty things at me :/

```
char DaysOfWeek[] = { 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday' };
```

Comment: Well, read closely at those **naughty things** first, I'm sure they are helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088622/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-strings-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array of all NSDate for a week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957200/array-of-all-nsdate-for-a-week)

Answer (score 4):

try

```
char * DaysOfWeek[] = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
```

Comment: What is the asterisk in between char and DaysOfWeek?

Comment: It indicates a pointer to `char`, rather than a `char`.  So you're declaring an array of strings, rather than an array of characters (which can be a string).

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you're defining an Array of Characters, which is just a single string. You'd want a 2D array of characters, ie. `char**`, `char*[]`, or `char[][]` to hold multiple strings/words. Also, you need to use double quotes `" "` rather than single quotes `' '` when holding Strings in C.

The next step from here depends on your errors, I would say. I also don't think you can initialize a 2D array inline like that. You'd have to do something like `char[][] days = { {'M', 'o', 'n', 'd', 'a', 'y'}, ... }` I believe.

Comment: Good answer, well done on breaking 1k. You can initialize it as in chouaib's answer. see here: http://ideone.com/jQ7oyI

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

1. You need to use double quotes in C literal strings.
2. This is a two dimensional array, you need to give some constant value to the second dimension.

Like this:

```
char DaysOfWeek[][20] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, you need to use double quotes (`"foo"`) to enclose strings.  Single quotes ('a') are for characters.

You also need to declare your variable as an array of strings, not as a single string, as Ricky Mutschlechner pointed out.